# Sqlite3 in angular4 electron desktop Application

Tags: angular, typescript, sqlite, electron

In angular 4 , electron desktop project,i wants to implement sqlite ,tried few packages and resources without any luck.I need to get sqlite to access from app.component.ts .Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a rest API. Try out expressjs.